# Reusing websocket connection object in Redux Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, websocket, redux-saga

I have a problem. I am connecting to the server with the help of websocket inside React Redux eventChannel. I have no problems with receivng event from the server but i cant sent event to the server. I understand, that i need to get websocket connection object which i create inside eventChannel to send event from react component for example.

```
export function* wsWatcher() {
    yield takeEvery("LOGIN_SUCCESS", wsConnectionWorker);
}

function* wsConnectionWorker() {
    const channel: EventChannel<boolean> = yield call(initWebsocket);
    while (true) {
        const action: Action<any> = yield take(channel);
        yield put(action);
    }
}

function initWebsocket(): EventChannel<any> {
    return eventChannel((emitter) => {

    let id: string | undefined;
    let intervalId: number;

    const initConnection = () => {
        const connectionUrl: string = "ws://localhost:4000" 
            
        let ws = new WebSocket(connectionUrl);
        
        ws.onopen = () => {
            id && ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "GET_USER_ID", id }));

            intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "PING" }))
            }, 30000)
        };

        ws.onclose = (e) => {
            console.log("Reconnect in 4s");
            intervalId && clearInterval(intervalId);
            id && setTimeout(initConnection, 4000); 
        };
    };

    initConnection();

    return () => {
        console.log("Socket off");
    };
});
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable in the module's scope and store connection object in it after first init. Later whenever you need the connection, just use this variable.

This works since modules are cached in nodejs. That is, the code in modules in run only when they're first imported, and later imports use the cached module.

For further reference, read more: [Modules Caching](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)

You can also have a function for this, like `getConnection` function in this code. Whenever you need the websocket connection, call this function and it'll create connection only once.

```typescript
export function* wsWatcher() {
    yield takeEvery("LOGIN_SUCCESS", wsConnectionWorker);
}

function* wsConnectionWorker() {
    const channel: EventChannel<boolean> = yield call(getConnection);
    while (true) {
        const action: Action<any> = yield take(channel);
        yield put(action);
    }
}

// store the EventChannel after first init
let wsConnection: EventChannel<any> = null;

// create WS connection on first call
// reuse that connection in further calls
function getConnection(): EventChannel<any>{
  if(!wsConnection){
    wsConnection = initWebsocket();
  return wsConnection;
}

function initWebsocket(): EventChannel<any> {
    return eventChannel((emitter) => {

    let id: string | undefined;
    let intervalId: number;

    const initConnection = () => {
        const connectionUrl: string = "ws://localhost:4000" 
            
        let ws = new WebSocket(connectionUrl);
        
        ws.onopen = () => {
            id && ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "GET_USER_ID", id }));

            intervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "PING" }))
            }, 30000)
        };

        ws.onclose = (e) => {
            console.log("Reconnect in 4s");
            intervalId && clearInterval(intervalId);
            id && setTimeout(initConnection, 4000); 
        };
    };

    initConnection();

    return () => {
        console.log("Socket off");
    };
});
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. But I am confused. When I import wsConnection, I have an object with such properties: take, flush and close. I think, its redux saga properties. Can I save a "ws" object, which I get here: "let ws = new WebSocket(connectionUrl);"?

Comment: You can. However, if you're using cached WebSocket, you should be careful while adding `onopen`, `onclose` event listeners to it, since those event listeners might already exist.

Comment: So i make a global variable, save ws variable to it and export it? Then I can import it and use how i want to?

Comment: Yes, make a global variable and preferably a function `getWs()` too. `getWs` should return the already available instance or create one and return.
You will have to change the `onopen` & `onclose` logic in this case. If you can share what you want to achieve with this saga, I will modify my code.

Comment: I have created a variable and save ws object to it right after "let ws = new WebSocket()" string. I can import it now and use it in my click events, for example. 

What i wanted is to have access to ws from my react component in order to send event to the server. There is a little problem with creating global varible. If i use this variable inside component (not in event handler or smth else) it will say, that it is still in connecting state. But in handlers all is good